# Fantasy TV series from the 90s

Tags: story-identification, tv

I vaguely remember watching a fantasy series when I was a kid. All I remember is a scene of doctors wearing all red, they have red gloves which are able to go inside people. For the life of me I cannot remember the name or anything else from this series.

Comment: Was it animated? Live action?

Comment: it was Live action

Answer (score 5):

Is it White Dwarf?
The pilot is on still up on youtube.
It's about a Doctor in the future serving his internship on a distant planet.
The Doctors in the series have special red gloves that allow them to operate inside a patient.

Comment: Welcome to the community !  It's typical when answering a question to provide some details as to why you think your answer fits the question criteria.  Please consider providing some details as to why you think White Dwarf could be the series the questioner is asking about.

Comment: Never heard of this, but apparently Pac may be true, here's a link, you'll see the red/orange gloves at the beginning of the video [link](http://youtu.be/hKDwdWZp6lI)

Comment: If confirmed/accepted, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21683/sci-fi-fantasy-tv-pilot-from-the-90s-about-a-frontier-doctor