# 90s fantasy movie about a magic world split light and dark

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying identify a movie I saw on tv in 1995-1996. It was about a world that is split into a light side and a dark side. They are separated by a wall. One of the female characters could shape shift into a large cat.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35470/fantasy-tv-series-from-the-90s/

Answer (score 10):

I think this is the TV movie [White Dwarf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Dwarf_(1995_film)) from 1995, viewable on youtube here:

From the wiki description:

> In the year 3040, New York medical student Driscoll Rampart (Neal
>   McDonough) is completing his internship on Rusta, a rural planet which
>   due to it being tidally locked to its primary, is divided into
>   contrasting halves of day and night with the halves separated by a
>   wall. The two sides are involved in a civil war: The day side
>   containing a Victorian-styled colony is at odds with the night
>   containing a medieval kingdom.

And from a more detailed plot summary [here](http://www.lifeofanactor.com/dwarf.htm), there is a shape shifter boy who can turn into a big cat, and who also at one point takes the form of a woman:

> Driscoll seeks refuge outside, but the wind is up. A child patient
>   nicknamed Never meets him. Never is an empathic shape-shifter whose
>   powers are known to the Rustians as Proteus Syndrome. He is a societal
>   pariah to his wealthy parents as he **morphs uncontrollably** into
>   anything from a boy-sized raven to a **panther.** He can even change into
>   the loved ones he finds in the minds of the people nearest in
>   proximity to him -- including Driscoll's recently deceased fiancé.
>
> Never takes the form of a **mysterious and beautiful woman** that Driscoll
>   recognizes and who speaks forlornly of "our son." Driscoll had a wife
>   and son, but Driscoll caught a disease and passed it to them. He
>   recovered, they did not. Driscoll forms an attachment to the abandoned
>   Never and helps the boy get a handle on his physical disease by
>   providing love and psychological grounding.