# Show about half of the world on perpetual night and the other on day.

Tags: story-identification

The show that used to be on tv where half the world was in perpetual night and the other half was in perpetual day? I think there was a wall that went around the world so that the people on the night side couldn’t enter the day side.. and.. that’s all I remember about it. It was on either in the late 80's or early 90's. I don't remember much since I was really young when it was on.

Comment: That's pretty vague,. Any more detail? Has it been a series, a feature movie? Could think of lots of stuff, although many being a bit too late for this: **Judge Dredd** had a huge wall around the city, with inside the city being portrayed by night most of the time. **Married... with Children** had a three-part episode with two towns in England having permanent day/night due to a curse. And then there'd be **Dark City** playing in... well, a Dark City. I also remember similar themes with huges walls in other series such as **Andromeda**.

Comment: @Mario: I don't think it's that vague. There can't be many shows where the *premise* was that half the world was in permanent daylight, and half was in permanent night.  (That's certainly not the premise of Judge Dredd, or Dark City.)

Comment: From a plot/content standpoint, true, but I remember so many movies from my childhood that turned out to be quite a bit different watching them as an adult, especially if the plot is more complicated than "A shoots B" and you didn't understand or follow it at all.

Comment: There's an episode from an early season of Stargate: SG-1 that takes place on a planet which seems similar - the Land of Light sends people into the darkness when they become 'infected' and revert to a Neanderthal-like state.  It was only one episode, though, and >50% of it took place on Earth - unlikely to be what you mean.

Comment: And there's also the Star Trek TNG episode [The Dauphin](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Dauphin_(episode%29). But I don't believe the OP means a single episode from an otherwise unrelated series.

Comment: It would help to get more information - such as whether this was live action or animated, what country it aired in, and whether it was on a network, cable, or syndicated - all that often helps people pinpoint the show.

Comment: I seem to remember the same, except I can't for the life of me remember the name! I just always assumed it was a movie. I remember the night and day side. I remember the main character was a male doctor - young - who was working on the day side and had somehow entered this world (wherever it was) from our world. I remember because I recall another character asking about sunsets and the young doctor guy explaining it. I remember the king on the night-side was like this monster thing that had imprisoned a princess? And was force-feeding her something to keep her young for centuries. Or decades?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35470/fantasy-tv-series-from-the-90s/

Answer (score 10):

Possibly *[White Dwarf](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114926/?ref_=ttqt_qt_tt)*. As far as I know never got beyond the pilot.

> *On a dying planet where a white dwarf sun rules a world divided by dark and light... A legend is about to be born.*

Comment: If this is ever confirmed, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21683/sci-fi-fantasy-tv-pilot-from-the-90s-about-a-frontier-doctor