# What fantasy TV miniseries had immortality as the ultimate punishment?

Tags: story-identification, miniseries

I vaguely remember this fantasy-esque miniseries (or was it a made for TV movie?) that featured a society where some of the worst criminals were punished with immortality along with imprisonment as a form of ultimate punishment.  Basically, if I recall correctly, being immortal was seen as a curse and once you were immortal you could be kept imprisoned by other immortals for millennium or longer.

Offenders were made immortal by being strapped to a chair with their mouth forced open and some kind of lizard-like humanoid would spit/excrete some kind of mucusy substance into their mouth, kind of gross.  I only saw a few parts of the show so I could be misremembering or misunderstanding any or all of it.  But I do distinctly remember immortality being administered as a punishment to at least one character.

I think this miniseries or TV movie was made some time in the 90s, but it could be late 80s for all I know.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I did some searching but didn't see it.  "Help identifying unknown fantasy movie/show where prisoners are punished with immortality?" is probably a closer dup.  But I guess we funnel everything through whatever isn't closed, seems a little strange.

Comment: It's already considered a duplicate of the other.  I tend to point all of them to the same one, so there's a base answer.  Not sure if that's the accepted procedure or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely [White Dwarf](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114926/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1995).

From [this summary](http://www.lifeofanactor.com/dwarf.htm) (emphasis mine):

> Elsewhere in this fantastical world dwells a fantastic, mythical character with **tusks and horns** -- a creature named Osh. Osh is the warden of the Dark Sider King's prison, The Keep. His prime charge is Lady X, a beautiful "young" woman more than 500 years old who was convicted of having created a plague on Earth that killed billions -- though she pleads she is innocent. She is kept alive by Osh's ability to secrete a hormone that affords an entirely undesired **immortality**. The only problem is that this big, lumbering beast is also **in love** with her.

---

It's a memorable movie and has been asked about a couple times.  Related questions that might have more details that could match:

[Show about half of the world on perpetual night and the other on day.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36228/show-about-half-of-the-world-on-perpetual-night-and-the-other-on-day/36229#36229?) Which has a link to the full movie.

[Fantasy TV series from the 90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35470/fantasy-tv-series-from-the-90s?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[90s fantasy movie about a magic world split light and dark](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35470/fantasy-tv-series-from-the-90s?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Help identifying unknown fantasy movie/show where prisoners are punished with immortality?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/173965/78394)