# Title of old Sci-fi movie, doctor goes to strange world

Tags: story-identification, movie

I trying to find the title of a science fiction movie I watched some years ago. Unfortunately I don't know how old the movie might be (or was at the time).

All I have to go on is a few memory fragments:

- A doctor travels to a strange world
- There is some sort of strife on this world, a war I believe
- Some people (at least one is shown as I remember) have the power to shout, or scream, at animals (and possibly humans) and thereby kill them. The scene I remember a dark skinned man uses this ability to kill a threatening leopard (or similar). (He inhales deeply and roars wordlessly.)
- There is a prison with a special prisoner, a woman I think. The prison guard is a large alien being
- There is a red ocean. I think the prisoner is brough there at some point though I can't remember why

I will add to this if I can remember any more details, but chances are slim since it was quite long ago that I watched it.

If you have any idea what the movie might be, I'd be very grateful.

**Edit:**
At the request of [@FuzzyBoots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/23243/fuzzyboots) who pointed out that there is a previously answered question for the same title [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21683/sci-fi-fantasy-tv-pilot-from-the-90s-about-a-frontier-doctor).

This question adds details about some scenes and occurances that are not mentioned in the older question. Notably, voice powers, aliens and red ocean. Some of these details would likely have led me to find the previous question before posting my own.

Comment: What country was this shown in?  Was it a mainstream film or something produced for TV?  Roughly how long ago did you see it?

Comment: I watched the movie in sweden on a channel named "TV4 Sci-fi" which no longer exists. I didn't know any of the answersto your questions, but Steve-O found it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The movie you are looking for is [White Dwarf (1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Dwarf_(1995_film)).

It was originally a failed pilot for a TV show, which was later aired as a "TV movie special event" by Fox.  I'm not sure if it was ever released on home video (VHS, DVD or otherwise.)  I certainly haven't had much luck finding a copy to purchase.  All I have is a (shitty) VHS recording I made when it aired back in '95.

- Dr Driscoll Rampart is a recent graduate looking to complete his residency on a backwater planet with potential for "stories" he can recount to his clientele in New York when he returns to Earth.  He picks Rusta, a planet divided in two parts - one side is always day, the other is always night.
- There is a war going on between the light and the dark, although we don't see much in the way of actual combat in the movie.
- Doctor Akada, the chief in the Rusta clinic where Dr Rampart goes, has been taught the power to "take life" with his voice, which he uses on the Rusta version of a puma which finds its way into the clinic.  (I forget the name of the animal, but it's important that you keep talking in order to prevent it from attacking.)
- There is a prison on the border between Light and Dark, governed by an alien being.  He has a princess held captive, who is kept eternally young by way of a secretion the alien warden produces.
- The red ocean (the Sea of Tears) is seen a couple of times in the film.  At the end, the princess is allowed to leave her prison, briefly, because the warden is in love with her and can no longer deny her the respite.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for helping me out. Now, to find a copy....